# apt command does not cache the .deb files?

Tags: apt

When using `apt-get` to install or upgrade a package, a copy of that package (the .deb file) will be saved in: `/var/cache/apt/archives` 
but when using `apt` command it's just download and installs the requested package and nothing will be saved in `/var/cache/apt/archives`.

Is it the default behavior of `apt` command?
Is there any switch/config to makes `apt` cache the deb files? (to have a backup of deb files)

I'm running: ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS - With all updates.

Comment: As you've discovered the lower level `apt-get` does this. If your curious you can find all the configuration files used by apt in `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d` (in 16.04 and onward) for more information see `man apt`

Comment: What version of `apt` and Ubuntu? I cannot reproduce this on any current release.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you've reported could be a consequence of a bug filed way back in 2002,  [apt: apt-get clean should run weekly](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=160743#5)

> The apt package cache grows without bound; "apt-get clean" should be run regularly (a script in /etc/cron.weekly would be fine).  Without such a script, apt runs the danger of filling up smaller disks, especially on systems run by less experienced Debian adminstrators.

This was reported [fixed in 2016](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=160743#117).

However, the code suggested to prevent the automatic removal of .debs after successful installation of the package needed further work as a result of another bug, [New option in apt "APT::Keep-Downloaded-Packages" is ignored](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=812111).

> The new option "APT::Keep-Downloaded-Packages" is ignored in configuration item "Dir::Etc::Parts" and in configuration item "Dir::Etc::Main".

Those interested may read the bugs and also `/usr/share/doc/apt/NEWS.Debian.gz` on your system (which can be opened by right-clicking and choosing "Open with gedit").

On my fully updated 16.04 LTS, `apt policy` has:

```
apt:
  Installed: 1.2.19
  Candidate: 1.2.19
```

and `/usr/share/doc/apt/NEWS.Debian.gz` has:

> apt (1.2~exp1) experimental; urgency=medium
>
> [ Automatic removal of debs after install ]
>   After packages are successfully installed by apt(8),
>   the corresponding .deb package files will be
>   removed from the /var/cache/apt/archives cache directory.
>
> This can be changed by setting the apt configuration option
>    "Binary::apt::APT::Keep-Downloaded-Packages" to "true". 
>   E.g:
>
> # echo 'Binary::apt::APT::Keep-Downloaded-Packages "true";' \ > /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/01keep-debs
>
> Please note that the behavior of apt-get is unchanged. The
>   downloaded debs will be kept in the cache directory after 
>   they are installed. To enable the behavior for other tools, 
>   you can set "APT::Keep-Downloaded-Packages" to false.

It maybe worth noting that `apt` is still evolving vis-à-vis `apt-get` and that users going this route should keep checking to see if code used in previous versions still works in the future.

Comment: Binary::apt::APT::Keep-Downloaded-Packages "true";' Did the job, thanks ;)