# How does apt install non .deb files?

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, tar

I want to know how does apt install non .deb files like tar.gz..etc. I want to install eclipse.but it is available in .tar.gz file.I had installed eclipse from `apt install eclipse` but i didn't find any .deb file of eclipse in `/var/cache/apt/archives/`these means apt must've been installing eclipse from .tar.gz file?if yes then **where are .tar.gz files are stored by apt? and How does apt install non .deb files?**

Comment: Bit of a jump to assume Apt is doing anything but downloading packages from its sources and feeding that into `dpkg`. That's what it's designed to do.

Comment: `apt install`downloads and INSTALLS a package. Why are you looking for a deb  or tar after that? What is your goal?

Comment: @Pilot6 I want to keep .deb files handy so that i don't need to download them again.But for eclipse i cant find .deb file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### APT

- APT only installs softwares using `.deb` packages, and
- By default the `apt` command does not cache the `deb` files:

  > [apt command does not cache the .deb files?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/897513/apt-command-does-not-cache-the-deb-files)
  >   [Where are packages stored installed with APT in Ubuntu 16.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/794983/where-are-packages-stored-installed-with-apt-in-ubuntu-16-04)

  It download and install the package and after installation was done it will remove the `deb` packages.

Apt is only used to do package management using `dpkg` and `deb` packages, it's a high level tools which make installation of packages easier.

To get download link of "eclipse" package:

```
$ apt download eclipse --print-uris |& grep -Po "http.*?deb"
http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/e/eclipse/eclipse_3.8.1-8_all.deb
```

or to download it in current directoey:

```
$ apt download eclipse
```

#### Tar

- To install "eclipse" using `tar` files just extract the archive somewhere and run its executable file.
- The other situation is when you download a `tar` archive containing the software source code which depend on the software you should follow some instruction to compile and install it

Comment: Does apt downloads .deb file of eclipse?

Comment: Yeah, but after installation was finish it will remove them, if you want to keep the `deb` files in `/var/cache/apt/archives/` use `apt-get install` or follow one of the links in my answer to reconigure `apt` to make it keep the `deb` files.

Answer (score 1):

Apt doesn't install non-deb files.

Your question is not very clear to me.

If you want to install `eclipse`, you run

```
sudo apt install eclipse
```

This will really install `eclipse`. Why do you want to find a deb file or a tar.gz after that?

If you need the source of `eclipse` package, you can also get it by

```
sudo apt source eclipse
```

This will download the sources including the tarball.