# How to leave deb files in cache after installing? APT::Clean-Installed "0" has no effect

Tags: apt, package-management, 20.04, apt-cache

I have an HDD installation that has spare space and I would like it to be a backup deb archive. But even with `APT::Clean-Installed "0";` in apt.conf and verified with `apt-config dump` all newly-installed packages are deleted from `/var/cache/apt/packages/`.

`APT::Periodic::AutocleanInterval "0";` so it should be disabled. And I can download installed packages with `apt-get download` but I want them to be kept, not removed right after installing.

Comment: Isn't using `apt-get install` instead of `apt install` supposed to leave debs in `/var/apt/cache` on a default system?

Comment: Is it? I always thought of `apt` as a replacement for `apt-get` plus features from some other apt-related commands. Anyway, I'll try that, thank you.

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/a/897605/248158 and https://askubuntu.com/a/794987/248158

Comment: You are completely correct. Should we close this question as a duplicate? Or, alternatively, just create a short answer with the links and I'll mark it as solved.

Comment: I think it's better if you vote to close it as a duplicate. You can do so. I'll cast the first vote to close.

Comment: I forgot one thing. Can you please post a really short answer just so I mark the question as solved it shows green in the list? :)

Comment: Sorry, but the way the site is set up, once a question is closed for whatever reason, nobody can post answers. Further, users who aren't signed in (or maybe don't have enough rep) won't even see this question; they'll be automatically directed to the "original".